# Limit Bandwidth using Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bandwidth

**Intro** - We are planning on applying for Bandwidth-on-Demand from our ISP which gives us upto 8Mbps of data upsteam/downstream. If we exceed the allowable bandwidth the ISP will bill us for additional cost per Mb of data exceeded.

**Question** - is there a way to setup an ubuntu server to limit the total upstream and downstream bandwidth on the internet facing interface (uplink) to 8Mbps?

Additional info - the server will also work as a gateway server distributing traffic to four subnets each with his own interface.

Answer (score 2):

Go low-complexity, just set your ethernet port to 10Mbps, the natural peaks and troughs will mean you're unlikely to over the 8Mbps.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be that easy. Anyway i'll try your suggestion. How about rate limiting on the LAN side ethernet ports? Something that I can use cron to schedule the rate limiting.

Comment: +1 for a very KISS solution.

Answer (score 1):

you could just setup tc on the interface and set the ceil rate to 8mbit.